# How to Convert Existing MySQL Schema to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, data-modeling

I have a MySQL database and would like to have a similar structure in Core Data. I am very new with using Core Data with Xcode. I have a few fundamental questions if I am doing the right thing.

My Mysql DB looks similar to this:

```
table.caveconditions
  visibilityID
  percolationID
  xxxx

table.visibility
  visibilityID
  visibilityValue
```

...and so on. I would then connect the tables using JOINS

Now, I have done the Core Data modeling like this but I am not quite sure if this is the right approach.

Would be great if someone of you could tell me if this is the right way to do it. In the end I would like to use JSON strings to dump the mysql table into core data.

Thanks a lot
Chris

[image]

I have created the new schema. Is this right?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks good except for all the "xxxID" attributes e.g. `caveID`. You also need to follow the naming conventions.

You have the same attribute names with (presumably) the same values in two or more entities. This is necessary in SQL for joins but in Core Data, this is handled by objects and relationships.

Each object in Core Data is automatically universally unique. This means when you create a relationship from one object to another, that relationship concrete identifies on specific unique object.

This means you only need an attribute like `caveID` in the actual entity that `caveID` designates which in this case is (presumably) the `Caves` entity. You don't need the attribute in the `CavesConditions` entity or any other entity that has a relationship to the "Caves" entity.

(If the `xxxID` were just artifacts of SQL, you don't actually need them at in Core Data unless some external database your app interacts with requires them.)

A good rule of thumb to use is that any particular value should show up on only one side of a relationship and, ideally, only once in the entire data model.

Naming conventions are a little different than SQL. A Core Data entity isn't a table. An entity is more akin to a class. Each entity is supposed to describe a single instance of a managed object. How many of those instances end up in the object graph is irrelevant. Therefore, entity names are singular.

In this case, `Caves` should be `Cave`, `Countries` should be `Country` and so on.

Relationships are named after the entity they target. It is not immediate obvious but each reciprocal relationship (the default) on the visual data model editor is actually two relationships because there is one relationship description for each side. Each side has the name of the entity targeted. By convention to-one relationships have a singular name and a to-many relationship has a plural name.

So:

```
Caves.relConditions<-->>CaveConditons.getCave
```

...would become

```
Cave.conditons<-->>CaveConditon.cave
```

The naming conventions are important because Objective-C uses conventions names to generate and search for accessor methods.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So I don't need all the xxIDs to reference to another Entity because it is handled by Core Data with Relationships? I would still keep the Cave.caveID in order to be able to search for a specific caveID? I will try to do all the changes tonight and will edit my previous post. Hopefully I have understood everything right.

Comment: The new data model looks good except that you should name the relationship on each side by the object it targets on the other side e.g. `Flow.flows` points to `CaveCondition` so the relationship should be named something like `Flow.conditions`. That makes it easy in code to understand what the relationship targets. `Flow.flows` implies that the relationship targets another flow object. However from the other side `CaveCondition.flow` make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

CoreData is NOT a database.  Remodel your data as simply as you can and in a way that suits how it will be used in your application and do not think about joins or structure based optimization.  You do not have control over the backing schema of a CoreData object model.  This is the hardest concept you must get over when starting to use CoreData, but once you do, you will be better off.

Comment: I agree with your answer. BUT I also have to find a way how to keep the data between Core Data and the online MySQL DB in sync. If I completely restructure Core Data I would need a more complex method to change it back to JSON in order to import it in my MySQL db. What do you think?

Comment: Personally, I think keeping them "in sync" without some intermediary translation layer is not practical. Along those lines, if you're going to need some intermediary web service (or whatever) then you might as well make a data model that best suits your platform (in this case iOS) and use that intermediary layer to do the heavy lifting of converting it to a format usable by your platform and its data model.